# Run a linux partition on VirtualBox

Tags: partitioning, virtualbox, backup, dd, disk-image

On my computer, I had multiple partitions and operating systems.

```
/dev/sda1 -> recovery
/dev/sda2 -> linux
/dev/sda3 -> swap
/dev/sda4 -> windows
```

I made an image backup of the linux partition:

```
pv < /dev/sda2 > linux-backup.img
```

Then, I formatted everything from the laptop.

**How can I use this image in a new VirtualBox machine?**

I am only interested in the linux partition and want to use it inside a virtual machine for some time. I tried converting the image:

```
VBoxManage convertfromraw --format VDI linux-backup.img linux.vdi
```

... but this gives me a whole disk containing the data (`/dev/sda` inside the VM), not a partition (I guess I would need the data inside a `/dev/sda1`).
And the other problem is, that this is not bootable.

Does anyone have an idea?

UPDATE: updated the question to point out, that I will not use the partition simultaneously from the computer and from the VM! I just want to use it for some time in the VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command `VBoxManage convertfromraw` is meant for *disk* images, not partitions images.

You need to create a new disk containing a partition from your image.

### Disclaimer

The following instructions are adapted from [my another answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/920669/converting-a-physical-linux-machine-to-use-in-vmware) and I haven’t tested them for an image yet.

### Instructions

1. Create a new VM with a new virtual hard drive with a sufficient capacity. Boot a live distro.
2. Format the blank hard drive, create (at least) a single partition with equal or higher size than your image.
3. Restore your image to the newly created partition, e.g.

   ```
   dd if=/media/shared/partition.img of=/dev/sdb1
   ```
4. Optionally extend the restored filesystem to match the current partition size, e.g.

   ```
   resize2fs /dev/sdb1
   ```
5. [Restore GRUB using the chroot method.](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd)
6. Edit configuration files if necessary (especially `/etc/fstab`, `/etc/network/interfaces`).
7. Shut down the VM, detach the live distro media and boot your server clone.

### References

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/260094/taking-and-restoring-an-image-of-partition-with-dd
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67095/how-can-i-expand-ext4-partition-size-on-debian

Comment: That's basically what worked for me, I used different tools - pv instead of dd, grub-repair instead of chroot, but basically the same idea.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it using your .img file, but your goal is readily do-able using Clonezilla. Just take a Clonezilla backup of the partition, then boot your virtual machine using Clonezilla and restore the backup into it.

I actually just did this yesterday to test an 18.04 upgrade in a vm before doing it on the real machine.