# Creating a backup and save it on Windows NTFS

Tags: server, upgrade, permissions, backup

Let me describe my problem first:

At work, we have an Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS server which is obviously kinda outdated. I need to make a release upgrade and before that, there needs to be a backup.
We have a Windows 2012 Server which would have enough space to store the backup.
I googled and found a solution to keep the permissions, which would be lost if I just `cp -a everything`:

```
dd if=/path/to/dir bs=1G | gzip > /path/to/backup/backup.tar.gz
```

So in that .tar.gz file, the permissions should be kept.

My idea was it to run the dd for every dir which I needed to backup:

`/etc, /home, /var`

Next step would be to create a package list to reinstall all the packages.
Found a solution here: (it's german but I guess you understand what they do)

[apt-get create package list](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Paketverwaltung/Tipps/#Paketliste-zur-Wiederherstellung-erzeugen)

After that, I should have a directory `/backup/` where all the `.tar.gz` files and the package lists are. This dir I would copy to our Windows server and do the release-upgrade on the Ubuntu server. If the upgrade messes with the system I can easily restore everything if I run the dd with reversed if and of.

Now my question(s):

Did I miss anything (in `general/directories` I need to restore the `System/etc`)?

Is there a better way to do it?

I hope my English isn't too bad and thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Can you reboot the server and boot a live medium? If yes, there is a ready-to-use solution for backups called Clonezilla. IMHO you should either _upgrade_ (using `do_release_upgrade`) or _replace_ your OS, don’t mix them (using a package list for a different OS version, particular directory from the old version, etc.) unless the more straightforward methods fail.

Comment: `dd` can be used to copy a file or a partition or a whole drive (cloning), but here I think you should use `tar` (to get a 'tar.gz` file: `sudo tar -cvzf /path/to/backup/backup-of-dirx.tar.gz /path/to/dirx`

Comment: Sadly no live boot possible. The package list was more of an idea to remember to packages which were installed. Like in a django project you normally have a requirements.txt where all the python libs are wrote in.

So the sudo tar is the better option?
and run that for all my dirs to backup?

Comment: Yes, you can read `man tar` and you can find good tutorials about `tar` via the internet.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Several answers at [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages) may be useful for you to identify which program packages you may want in the next version of Ubuntu Server.

Comment: Tanks again for your help.

Comment: You are welcome and good luck :-)

Comment: If you cannot reboot your machine, then [my answer on cloning a running server](https://askubuntu.com/a/920680/250300) might come in handy.